# Which tools can I use to extract texts from ebc files in Nintendo Switch ROM

Tags: file-format

I encountered *.ebc files when i was trying to yank the dialog texts from the Nintendo switch game for my research project. The dialogs seems to be in binary ebc files. What kind of file format is that? Is it possible to separate the binary data from the the texts? Which tools are better to use?

Comment: What game? Games like to use game-specific formats instead of standard formats

Comment: buddy mission bond. I ended up scrapping the binary file and extracted all kanji and kana from it